# Even after using @AttributeOverrides to change attribute names, I am still getting Repeated Column error

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-mvc

```
package com.hashedin.employeemanagementsystem.entities;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@Table(name="employee")
@Entity(name="User")
public class User{

    public User(){
        this.individual = new Individual();
        this.workExperience = null;
        this.experienceInMonths = null;
        this.jobRole = null;
        this.primaryContact = null;
        this.secondaryContact = null;
        this.employeeID = null;
        this.joiningDate = null;
        this.employeeCategory = null;
        this.exitDate = null;
        this.educationDetails = null;

    }

    @Id
    //Employee 4 digit ID
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="employee_id")
    private Long empID;

    //employee ID Code
    @Column(name = "employee_code_id")
    private String employeeID;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name="first_name", column = @Column(name="employee_first_name")),
            @AttributeOverride(name="last_name", column = @Column(name="employee_last_name")),
            @AttributeOverride(name="email", column = @Column(name="employee_email")),
            @AttributeOverride(name="phone", column = @Column(name="employee_phone")),
    })
    private Individual individual;

    //Primary and Secondary Contacts
    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "email", column = @Column(name = "primary_contact_email")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "Individual.first_name", column = @Column(name = "primary_contact_first_name")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "last_name", column = @Column(name = "primary_contact_last_name")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "phone", column = @Column(name = "primary_contact_phone"))
    })
    private Individual primaryContact;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name="email", column = @Column(name="secondary_contact_email")),
            @AttributeOverride(name="first_name", column=@Column(name="secondary_contact_first_name")),
            @AttributeOverride(name="last_name", column=@Column(name="secondary_contact_last_name")),
            @AttributeOverride(name="phone", column=@Column(name="secondary_contact_phone"))
    })
    private Individual secondaryContact;

    //jobRole
    @Embedded
    private JobRole jobRole;

    //joining date and exit date (mentioned for Fixed Employees / probation period)
    @Column(name="joining_date")
    private Date joiningDate;

    @Column(name="exit_date")
    private Date exitDate;

    //category, experience and highest degree
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Education educationDetails;

    @Column(name="employee_category")
    private String employeeCategory;

    @Column(name="total_experience")
    private Integer experienceInMonths;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="employee_id")
    private List<Employment> workExperience;

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, Location location, String email, String phone, String employeeID, Individual primaryContact, Individual secondaryContact, Date joiningDate, String employeeCategory, Date exitDate, Integer experience, Education educationDetails, JobRole jobRole, List<Employment> exp) {
        this.individual = new Individual(firstName, lastName, location, email, phone);
        this.workExperience = exp;
        this.experienceInMonths = experience;
        this.jobRole = jobRole;
        this.primaryContact = primaryContact;
        this.secondaryContact = secondaryContact;
        this.employeeID = employeeID;
        this.joiningDate = joiningDate;
        this.employeeCategory = employeeCategory;
        this.exitDate = exitDate;
        this.educationDetails = educationDetails;
    }

    public Individual getIndividual() {
        return individual;
    }

    public void setIndividual(Individual individual) {
        this.individual = individual;
    }

    public Long getEmpID() {
        return empID;
    }

    public void setEmpID(Long empID) {
        this.empID = empID;
    }

    public Integer getExperienceInMonths() {
        return experienceInMonths;
    }

    public void setExperienceInMonths(Integer experienceInMonths) {
        this.experienceInMonths = experienceInMonths;
    }

    public List<Employment> getWorkExperience() {
        return workExperience;
    }

    public void setWorkExperience(List<Employment> workExperience) {
        this.workExperience = workExperience;
    }

    public JobRole getJobRole() {
        return jobRole;
    }

    public void setJobRole(JobRole jobRole) {
        this.jobRole = jobRole;
    }

    public Education getEducationDetails() {
        return educationDetails;
    }

    public void setEducationDetails(Education educationDetails) {
        this.educationDetails = educationDetails;
    }

    public Integer getExperience() {
        return experienceInMonths;
    }

    public void setExperience(Integer experience) {
        this.experienceInMonths = experience;
    }

    public Date getExitDate() {
        return exitDate;
    }

    public void setExitDate(Date exitDate) {
        this.exitDate = exitDate;
    }

    public String getEmployeeCategory() {
        return employeeCategory;
    }

    public void setEmployeeCategory(String employeeCategory) {
        this.employeeCategory = employeeCategory;
    }

    public String getEmployeeID() {
        return employeeID;
    }

    public void setEmployeeID(String employeeID) {
        this.employeeID = employeeID;
    }

    public Date getJoiningDate() {
        return joiningDate;
    }

    public void setJoiningDate(Date joiningDate) {
        this.joiningDate = joiningDate;
    }

    public Individual getPrimaryContact() {
        return primaryContact;
    }

    public void setPrimaryContact(Individual primaryContact) {
        this.primaryContact = primaryContact;
    }

    public Individual getSecondaryContact() {
        return secondaryContact;
    }

    public void setSecondaryContact(Individual secondaryContact) {
        this.secondaryContact = secondaryContact;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "empID=" + empID +
                ", employeeID='" + employeeID + '\'' +
                ", individual=" + individual.toString() +
                ", primaryContact=" + primaryContact +
                ", secondaryContact=" + secondaryContact +
                ", jobRole=" + jobRole +
                ", joiningDate=" + joiningDate +
                ", exitDate=" + exitDate +
                ", educationDetails=" + educationDetails +
                ", employeeCategory='" + employeeCategory + '\'' +
                ", experienceInMonths=" + experienceInMonths +
                ", workExperience=" + workExperience +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Still getting this error, please help:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boo
t/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceU
nit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.hashedin.emplo
yeemanagementsystem.entities.User column: email (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5
.3.5.jar:5.3.5]

This is what my Individual class looks like:

```
package com.hashedin.employeemanagementsystem.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Embeddable
public class Individual {
    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Embedded
    private Location location;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="phone")
    private String phone;

    public Individual(){
        this.firstName="";
        this.lastName="";
        this.location=null;
        this.email=null;
        this.phone=null;
    }

    public Individual(String firstName, String lastName, Location location, String email, String phone) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.location = location;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Individual{" +
                "firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", location=" + location +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", phone='" + phone + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no attrribute `first_name` there is `firstName`  the same for `last_name` the `name` has to match the name of the field **not** the name of the column and remove the `@Column` annotations from the `@Embeddable` those aren't needed.